# Javascript - onselect checkbox copy value to form field

Tags: javascript, html, checkbox

In a contactform to send an e-mail I can add the subject of the generated mail. I would like the visitor to select with checkboxes the subject.
Checkbox has as value "on" or "off". Not really interesting, so when checking te checkbox javascript has to change the value of the hidden 'subject' field to the 'define' subject.
1) My script doesn't work, why?
2) Is it more interesting to use onselect or onchange?
3) If user selects multiple checkboxes, how can I merge the strings? 
(note the prepared ' space' before the subjects).

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function define(addsubject){
    document.getElementById ('subject').value = addsubject.value;
    }
    </script>

    My question is about: 
<form>
    <input type="hidden" id="subject">

    <input type="checkbox" onselect="define(' Copywriting')">Copywriting &nbsp;<br>
    <input type="checkbox"  onchange="defineSubject(' Proofreading & Copy-editing')"> Proofreading & Copy-editing<br>
    ... etc.
</form>
```

Comment: *Is it more interesting?* what kind of question is that? Also, please limit yourself to a single question per question. See [ask] for more information. Finally, `input`s have a `value` attribute you can set in HTML. Why not just set that directly instead of using JavaScript?

Comment: Why don't you use a **value** attribute ? It's the best way you could do

Comment: not sure if this is what you are looking for: https://jsfiddle.net/2jod4jdv/10/

Comment: also you have a typo in your onchange attribute, `defineSkubject`

Comment: jsfiddle answered my question. Using 'onclick' and dropping .value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need following code 
`document.getElementById('subject').value = addsubject;`

addsubject is a string reference passed to the function by `onchange()`.

The onselect event is mostly used on `<input type="text">` or `<textarea>` elements.

For your third question you would have to track all checkbox upon form submit and add values to the string and assign to hidden input. Other way you can do is keep changing your string upon every onchange event on checkbox.

Comment: You answered question one and two.
For three I found a solution. Check below.

Answer (score 0):

The only problem remaining is that the user can check & uncheck multiple times creating a weird subject. But that I can accept.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function define(addsubject)
{
document.getElementById ('subject').value = document.getElementById ('subject').value.concat(addsubject);
}
</script>

 My question is about: 
<form>
    <input type="hidden" id="subject">

    <input type="checkbox" onclick="define('Copywriting ')">Copywriting &nbsp;<br>
    <input type="checkbox"  onclick="defineSubject('Proofreading & Copy-editing ')"> Proofreading & Copy-editing<br>
    ... etc.
</form>
```

Comment: what happens when you do tab and space to select the checkbox?